# Make list item title refinable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, managed-property, refiner, crawled-property

I have a set of project sites in Sharepoint 2013 on premises, each of which contains a list of content type `Project details`.

This content type contains columns for `Project Name`, `Project Manager` and `Project Status`.

I have use this to display info about multiple projects on a page, as search results.

I can find crawled properties like `ows_Project_x0020_Status` and `ows_Project_x0020_Manager` and I am able to map them to refiners.

But I cannot find any `ows_Project_x0020_Name`.

I would like to sort the search results on `Project Name`, and I also would like to use `Project Name` as a refiner (to get a list of all projects).

I have found out that the name of the field that I call `Project Name` is not only `Project Name`, it is also `Title`

But mapping `ows_Title` to a `RefinableString` and starting a full crawl does not seem to help. This was all I did to make `ows_Project_x0020_Status` and `ows_Project_x0020_Manager` refinable.

How can I make the list item `Title` (`Project Name`) refinable?

Comment: Why are you not useing proper internalnames by Setting the column Name to the internalname you want and then the Display Name. This only works on creating

Comment: In this case it was the Title field that was renamed Project Name, so no managed property had been created for Project Name. The Project Manager and Project Status columns were created new, so with those columns there were no issues.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, is to ask the administrator to change this using the administration tools on the server: 
Go to Search Schema, and check the sortable checkbox (and, if desired, also the refinable checkbox) for the managed property Title.